# По какой причине может не работать Тkinter в Pycharm?

Tags: python, tkinter

Если я пишу `from tkinter import *` , то всё работает, но если я пишу переменную и задаю ей название `Tk()`, то Pycharm мне пишет что такого имени нет. Тоже самое происходит с классом `Button`.
В чем может быть проблема?
Код:

```py
from tkinter import *

tk = Tk()
tk.geometry('200x200')


def click():
    print('clicked')
    tk.geometry('100x100')


def close():
    tk.destroy()


b1 = Button(text='Ussz', bg='red', command=click)
b2 = Button(text='Qite', bg='blue', command=close)
b1.pack()
b2.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

Он простой и бессмысленный так как я только учу пайтон.

Ошибка:

```
 tk = Tk()

NameError: name 'Tk' is not defined
```

Comment: приложите фрагмент кода и текст ошибки. Не мучайте людей

Comment: лично у меня данный hello world работает. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hello-world-in-tkinter/

Comment: Проверьте, что у вас нет рядом файлов с именем tkinter.py